# upgrade to 16.04 from 14 did not complete, how to fix?

Tags: upgrade

I ran the automatic upgrade from 14.something to 16.04...left it running overnight, and this morning found that install appeared to have stalled out and not completed 100%. Could not open terminal window, so rebooted. NOW the laptop boots to 16.04.2, but just to command line log-in....don't see the graphic windows type environment.

How do I either back up to what I had previous, or re-run the 16.04 install so that it completes successfully ?

Thanks for any advice and help !

---

UPDATE -   I followed the instructions from this and it seemed to fix the problem.

https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/rescuing-an-interrupted-ubuntu-upgrade/

THanks for the help and advice !!!

Comment: I would backup my data, and install fresh new 16.04

Comment: As Greg suggested backup and fresh install is the best and safest way to go right now, if you don't know how to do that, update your question and we'll answer

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, you should create an answer for your question (yes, you can answer your own question) and mark it as the solution for the sake of anyone who lands here with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE - I followed the instructions from this and it seemed to fix the problem.

https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/rescuing-an-interrupted-ubuntu-upgrade/

> First step is to boot the machine to a shell that you can use to
>   recover. This can be done in the standard system by using the Recovery
>   Mode. Press the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as the system boots up and
>   choose a recovery mode kernel from the menu that appears – it will be
>   labeled with "(recovery mode)" at the end of the line. The recovery
>   mode kernel will present you with the option to use a recovery shell.
>
> You could use the rescue mode by booting with an Ubuntu install CDROM
>   and entering "rescue" at the boot prompt, but then you must remember
>   to mount all of your partitions and to perform a chroot to /target
>   where the root partition is mounted.
>
> After the system has booted to the menu, select the item that says
>   "“Drop to root shell prompt with networking". This provides you with
>   the ability to update the software packages from the internet.
>
> When the prompt appears, start by making sure that all currently
>   installed programs are configured:
>
> ```
> dpkg --configure -a
> ```
>
> This may take a long time, depending on how many programs were
>   installed before the system stopped. Then go ahead and update the
>   current list of packages:
>
> ```
> apt-get update
> ```
>
> Following this, upgrade the software on the system:
>
> ```
> apt-get upgrade
> ```
>
> This last step, again, may take a long time to complete. You should
>   pay attention to the list of packages held back (listed at the top of
>   the output from this command); these packages will have to be
>   requested specifically. Usually, packages are held back because they
>   require new software or other drastic changes: the Linux kernel is
>   always held back. Use a command like this one to install these
>   packages:
>
> ```
> apt-get install some-package some-other-package
> ```
>
> You may have to repeat this more than once until all of the packages
>   have been installed and none are held back.
>
> Then, you should repeat the update and upgrade in order to completely
>   verify that the system is as updated as it can be:
>
> ```
> apt-get update  
> apt-get upgrade
> ```
>
> These last commands should execute quickly, as everything is probably
>   complete – however, it is not impossible that the upgrades would have
>   affected something that requires another upgrade. Not doing this
>   probably won’t matter, but why not do it anyway?
>
> Once done, a reboot is required to make sure that the old software is
>   no longer being used and all that is used is the new upgraded
>   software. Don’t just continue the boot: reboot.
>
> ```
> reboot
> ```
>
> One more thing can be done to clean up afterwards, possibly after the
>   reboot. At a command shell, enter this command to remove unneeded
>   software:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> ```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! However, giving a link isn't an answer. It would be great if you could mention the steps you took here instead.